# No USB debugging on Lenovo Tab 7 Essential

Tags: usb-debugging, lenovo, developer-options

My Lenovo Tab 7 Essential (TB-73041, Android 7) doesn't have the USB debugging option.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can ask me to take any screenshot